# SQL error fetching data: Invalid attribute name: 'undefined'

Tags: sql, sql-update, undefined

I am trying to update a row in my SQL table and it returns the error `error fetching data: Invalid attribute name: 'undefined'`.

I am using the query `UPDATE main.users SET password = "new_password" WHERE username = "bob";` in a database that has this:

```
[
  {
    '7': '109ea3ff-7f34-430c-809a-9e0bf30f6f63',
    __updatedtime__: 1686074006344,
    password: 'bobs_password',
    username: 'bob',
    public_key: 'pub_key_bob',
    __createdtime__: 1686074006344,
    private_key: 'priv_key_bob'
  },
  {
    '7': '1ef53c78-9d83-442a-a657-95e7fe8e9c25',
    __updatedtime__: 1686065945323,
    password: 'password',
    username: 'username',
    public_key: 'pub',
    __createdtime__: 1686062155523,
    private_key: 'priv'
  },
  {
    '7': '960ceff9-1bd9-4e1b-a3db-94038910ba5e',
    __updatedtime__: 1686074295087,
    password: '6eb228fb5b59ab49a45a48bdd9e5f0ed65b43afb52ec72cc825a567986630827',
    username: 'beans',
    public_key: '[7,35417]',
    __createdtime__: 1686074295087,
    private_key: '941907dc12db4d51a9f0ca21204bed34'
  },
  {
    '7': '9e3aabc3-8aed-42bb-8070-451442725305',
    __updatedtime__: 1686074118562,
    password: 'cheese',
    username: 'cheese',
    public_key: '[3,46003]',
    __createdtime__: 1686074118562,
    private_key: 'a8d8039d15cde5041eee14a8606e7273'
  },
  {
    '7': 'cf993545-8dc5-44bf-a72d-671cb206a4a2',
    __updatedtime__: 1686066512761,
    password: 'admin',
    username: 'admin_user',
    public_key: 'admin_key',
    __createdtime__: 1686066512761,
    private_key: 'admin_key'
  }
]
```

I am using HarperDb. I am also using an edited version of an example query that harperDb gave me, the example was:

`UPDATE dev.dog SET dog_name = 'penelope' WHERE id = 1`
Any help please ?

Comment: SQL has single quotes for string literals, e.g. `'bob'`. `"bob"` is a _delimited identifier_, e.g. a column name.

Comment: I tried that: `UPDATE main.users SET password = 'new_password' WHERE username = 'bob';` and it gave the same error